# limit_validation_errors resetting form values in submit handler

Tags: 8, forms

I have a custom button in my **`form_alter`** and a submit handler for that . I **`don't need validation`** for this button submit . I tried by giving **`limit_validation_errors`** to exclude all validation for the custom submission . When giving like this am **`not receiving any form values`** in submit handler . Any idea on how to resolve this issue ?

**TRY**

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id){
 //Additional button for the Save as Draft feature
  $form['actions']['draftsubmit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Save as Draft'),
      '#weight' => 1000,
      '#submit' => array('draft_form_submit'),
      '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),                       
     );              
}


/**
 * Handles the save as draft button submit 
 */
function draft_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    echo '<pre>';print_r($form_state->getValues());exit;echo '</pre>'; //Not getting values here 
    $name = $form_state->getValue('field_p_name')[0]['value'];
    $dc = $form_state->getValue('field_p_dc')[0]['value'];
    $sec_type = $form_state->getValue('field_p_sec_type')[0]['value'];
}
```

**UPDATE**

---

I have other validations in other modules form_alter like

```
 function othermodule_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id){
    $form['field_fwd_acl']['#element_validate'] = array('validate_IpAndNetworks');
    $form['field_fwd_dest_acl']['#element_validate'] = array('field_fqdn_validate');
    $form['field_amount_of_proxies']['#element_validate'] = array('field_instance_validate');
}
```

I mean these validations should not be worked when clicked on **`Save as Draft`** button is clicked

Comment: You can do a check for the clicked button in the #element_validate handlers.

Comment: Can u write a sample ?

Comment: I did below. see the third code block.

Comment: Okay that's grea t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#limit_validation_errors prevents values from being passed to the submit handler, since they have not been validated. You can whitelist values by passing the form element key to #limit_validation_errors:

```
'#limit_validation_errors' => [
  // format follows the same as in the form state values. Elements
  // that are not #tree will be a string. Nested elements will be
  // an array.
  'element1',
  ['wrapper','element2'],
];
```

If you want to limit validation, but need all the values in the submit handler, then it's better to not use #limit_validation_errors. Instead, you can wrap any validation in a conditional to check if the 'next' button was clicked:

```
if ($form_state->getTriggeringElement() == $form['actions']['next']) {
  // Do form validation here. If the 'back' button was clicked, this
  // validation code will not be clicked. It will only be validated if
  // next has been clicked.
}
```

Note that if you use #required, validation will still happen even with the above code, since #required is handled separately. In this case, I don't use #required, instead I'll add custom validation to the above code:

```
if ($form_state->getTriggeringElement() == $form['actions']['next']) {
  // Do form validation here. If the 'back' button was clicked, this
  // validation code will not be clicked. It will only be validated if
  // next has been clicked.
  if (!strlen($form_state->getValue('some_element')) {
    $form_state->setError('some_element', $this->t('Please fill in a value for some field'));
  }
}
```

Comment: I have other validations in form_alter . probably that need to change to the way as you said .

Comment: Yes, it has to be done to any validation handlers added in the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom validation handler to the button which I think will override the normal form validations (rather than an if statement in each normal validation handler)  If this is an entity for, I think the entity validates itself later so there might still be some validation there.

```php
$form['actions']['draftsubmit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Save as Draft'),
  '#weight' => 1000,
  '#submit' => array('draft_form_submit'),
  '#validate' = ['_draftsubmit_validate_callback'];  // this callback just does nothing. so everything is considered valid. 
);
```